# The client does not receive or save the authentication cookie in the header (server and client hosted on different domains)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, jwt

I have a simple task management application, the client is made with REACT and the backend is made with NODE JS. It has a simple login which from the server generates a token that it sends to the client as a cookie (using json web token for that) and the client receives it and stores it in the header (using js-cookie for that). Everything works fine locally, the problem is when I hosted them on different domains, the client is hosted on Netlify.app and the server on Render.com. When requesting the authentication cookie (token) of the user, it fails and returns an error which tells me that the token is not valid and denies me access: message: "Invalid token, Access denied".

```
import { TOKEN_SECRET } from "../config.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const authRequired = (req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;

  if (!token)
    return res.status(401).json({ Mensaje: "Token invalido, Acceso denegado" });

  jwt.verify(token, TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.status(403).json({ mensaje: "token invalido" });

    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
};
```

My jwt.js:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { TOKEN_SECRET } from "../config.js";

export function createAccessToken(payload) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    jwt.sign(payload, TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1d" }, (err, token) => {
      if (err) rej(err);
      res(token);
    });
  });
}
```

From client:
AuthContext.jsx:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import {
  registerRequest,
  loginRequest,
  verifyTokenRequest,
} from "../api/auth.js";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("El useAuth debe ser usado con un AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [FormErrors, setFormErrors] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const signup = async (user) => {
    try {
      const res = await registerRequest(user);
      setUser(res.data);
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (error) {
      if (Array.isArray(error.response.data)) {
        setFormErrors(error.response.data);
      }
      setFormErrors(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  const signin = async (user) => {
    try {
      const res = await loginRequest(user);
      setUser(res.data);
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (error) {
      if (Array.isArray(error.response.data)) {
        setFormErrors(error.response.data);
      }
      setFormErrors(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    Cookies.remove("token");
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    setUser(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (FormErrors.length > 0) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setFormErrors([]);
      }, 10000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [FormErrors]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function checkLogin() {
      const jCookies = Cookies.get();

      if (!jCookies.token) {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setLoading(false);
        return setUser(null);
      }
      try {
        const res = await verifyTokenRequest(jCookies.token);
        if (!res.data) {
          setIsAuthenticated(false);
          setLoading(false);
          return;
        }

        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        setUser(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setUser(null);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    checkLogin();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        signup,
        signin,
        logout,
        user,
        isAuthenticated,
        FormErrors,
        loading,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Axios authticator:

```
import axios from "./axios.js";

export const registerRequest = (user) => axios.post(`/register`, user);

export const loginRequest = (user) => axios.post(`/login`, user);

export const verifyTokenRequest = () => axios.get("/verify");
```

Axios instance:

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://exampleurl.com/api"
  withCredentials: true,
});

export default instance;
```

Investigating a little, I have only read that to avoid this problem, I must host both the server and the client on the same domain. However, this is only a practice project and I don't want to spend money on a VPS or Hosting. The other solution is with a Proxy, however I do not know how to configure a proxy. Is there anything else I can do to get the client to store the token as a cookie without having to move either the server or the client from where they are hosted, or do I have to pay for this to work?

PD: This is my first project with Node js and REACT

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is possible without a custom domain setup- you can't set the domain of a cookie to be a different domain. E.g. myapp.netlify.com can't set a cookie for mybackend.onrender.com.

If you're not 100% attached to netlify, it's [pretty easy (and free)](https://dashdashhard.com/posts/mern-stack-on-render/#:%7E:text=Step%202%3A%20Deploy%20your%20React%20frontend) to host your react app on render alongside your app. That way you'd be able to use cookies because both apps would be on the same root domain of `onrender.com`

Comment: Good day, I finally decided to use a VPS. I just need to configure it so that it doesn't block CORS, but that's a different topic. In any case, thank you very much for your help.